# WhenEvent in Stochastic Differential Equation

Tags: differential-equations, stochastic-calculus, event-detection

Is there a way to add events with  `WhenEvent` or similar when using `ItoProcess`?

Minimal example of my problem would be to change sign when diffusion hits a wall. (Post processing is no good - I need to change several things in the actual problem)

As per edit request a sample SDE:

$$ d x = \frac{\sin x}{1 - \cos x} dt + dW $$

with looping boundary. That is, with $x = \pi + \epsilon$ changing to  $x = -\pi + \epsilon$ whenever $x > \pi$ and analog for $x < -\pi$

(Equation is well behaved within $(-\pi,\pi)$ domain)

Comment: I might help if you provided an actual example of SDE + events you would like to solve.

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as *Mathematica* code instead of just images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you.  You may find [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: I don’t think it’s possible, but I’m waiting for someone to show me I’m wrong.  `RandomFunction` on SDE does not seem to be programmed to handle events.  (In the example you might be able to post-process the time series, but that seems rather specific to the SDE and event.)

Answer (score -3):

This shows how it works:

```
proc = ItoProcess[\[DifferentialD]X[
     t] == -α WhenEvent[x[t] == 1., 
      x[t] -> -x[t]] Exp[-α t] Log[X0/K] X[
      t] \[DifferentialD]t + σ X[t] \[DifferentialD]W[t], 
  X[t], {X, X0}, t, W \[Distributed] WienerProcess[]]
Mean[proc[t]]
PDF[proc[t], x]
proc1 = proc /. {X0 -> 70, K -> 2, σ -> 0.1, α -> 0.3};
DiscretePlot[PDF[proc1[t], x], {x, 0, 10}]
CovarianceFunction[proc1, s, t]
```

The `DiscretePlot` is very time-consuming, so I shortened that. Definitely this does not work if the questions target to use `RandomFunction`.

```
Plot3D[CovarianceFunction[proc1, s, t], {s, 0, 5}, {t, 0, 5}, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]
```

The equation given in the question might not work because the denominator is singular at infinitely many points. Mathematica works on the `Complexes`.

In this methodolgoy `Mod` is an alternative.

```
proc4 = ItoProcess[\[DifferentialD]x[t] == 
   Sin[Mod[x[t], \[Pi]]]/(
     1 - Cos[Mod[x[t], \[Pi]]]) \[DifferentialD]t + \[DifferentialD]w[
      t], x[t], {x, 1}, t, w \[Distributed] WienerProcess[]]
```

(* ItoProcess[{{-(
Sin[Mod[x[t], [Pi]]]/(-1 + Cos[Mod[x[t], [Pi]]]))}, {{1}},
x[t]}, {{x}, {1}}, {t, 0}] *)

```
RandomFunction[proc4, {0., 1., 0.01}]
```

[image: RandomFunction]

Further extended:

```
    f[x_] := Piecewise[Table[{Sin[x - n*Pi - \[Epsilon]]/(1 - Cos[x - n*Pi - \[Epsilon]]), 
     -Pi + n*Pi + \[Epsilon] <= x <= Pi + n*Pi + \[Epsilon]}, {n, -5, 5}]]
Plot[f[x], {x, -6*Pi + \[Epsilon], 6*Pi + \[Epsilon]}]
```

works too with the RandomProcess representation and therefore complete. But still the problem remains that the function is singular for `2 n , Element[n,Integers]`.

```
ListLinePlot[%, Filling -> Axis]
```

[image: ListLinePlot]

Using the Fourier make this ideally periodic. For example:

```
p = Table[
   f[x], {x, \[Epsilon], 
    6 \[Pi] + \[Epsilon], (6 \[Pi] + \[Epsilon])/999}];
s = Fourier[p];
ListPlot[Abs[InverseFourier@s], PlotRange -> Full]
```

And the use this as an InterpolatingFunction of x: `Interpolation@InverseFourier@s`.